# How to change a variable in php according to browser width

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress-theming

In PHP, I'm trying to set the value of a variable `number` conditionally - so that it is dependent on the browser width or screen size (not sure which is most sensible).

I've read that I can't do this all in PHP itself but am confused as to how to approach this.

This is the situation I currently have...

> ```
> if ( fmod( $i, (int) number ) == 0 && $i != (int) $wp_query >post_count ) {
>           echo '</div><div class="row">';
>       } elseif ( $i == (int) $wp_query->post_count ) {
>           continue;
>       }
> ```

Can anybody help me resolve this issue please?

Many thanks,
Ed

Comment: Of course, the user could resize the browser window after you send the page. It's generally better to handle this kind of thing entirely in the client.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to do this please? I'm quite new to this...

Comment: Isn't there code in the other question? I don't think I could do a better job.

Comment: If you mean how to do it in the client, google responsive Javascript.

Comment: You can also use something like Bootstrap.